# Ping varies on different Ports with the same IP (Gaming related)?

Tags: networking, ping, connection, port, udp

I apologize if my question is "dumb" and not in the right category, I'm new here and I am genuinely curious about it.

Recently, there have been numerous complaints from users of the game Planetside 2 regarding poor connections, lag, and high ping issues, even tho their internet in general (pinging google) works fine. However, I have not encountered any of these problems, despite being located near the same area as those who are complaining and I am connecting to the same server.

So I did some tests using NetLimiter and discovered that when I connect to the game server, the server always has the same IP address, however, each time I disconnect and reconnect, the port of that IP changes. These ports are like 20115, 20121, 20130, 20133 and so on.

Now I wonder, is it possible that the ping varies depending on which port you are connected to, or is the ping consistent across all ports since the IP remains the same?

For example if I send a 1KB UDP packet to the Server IP located in Asia with port 20112 I get 250ms, but when I use port 20192 instead which is also related to the game I get 950ms several times.

If that's the case it could explain why some users have high pings, and others have no issues at all.

I'm specifically talking about UDP connections in case that matters.

Comment: Without knowing what is happening behind those ports, its impossible to say.

Comment: It is possible that these ports are on a network balancing appliance that shuffles different ports to different internal IPs that potentially handle different zones or groups of people within the game, but that sounds like a lot of hassle and a headache that could make things a lot more difficult to get going smoothly. As mentioned by Keltari we can only guess at the infrastructure. It could be a single machine (the server) just taking in different users, or it could be a cluster of servers and a network appliance.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible that the ping varies depending on which port you are connected to, or is the ping consistent across all ports since the IP remains the same?

Ping, as in latency or round-trip time, largely depends on the physical path taken to that IP address.

It is entirely possible for packets to same network to take two different paths depending on the exact address, and for packets from&to same IP address to take two different paths depending on the TCP or UDP port number (e.g. odd port numbers result in path A being chosen, even port numbers use path B).

This is called "ECMP" routing (equal-cost multipath), and can be used to balance traffic across two or four identical routers, but it can also be used to balance between paths through two entirely different carrier ISPs. If your ISP has more than one Internet connection, it might be using ECMP at least for *some* of its routes. (For example, the path between two of my VPS servers switches between Telia and Cogent.)

Importantly, this depends not just on the destination address & port, but also on the *source* as well. (Remember that packets also have a source port, too!) So if you create two different sockets, they'll choose different source ports and may result in different paths even if the destination is exactly the same. (And on top of that, if you're behind NAT, your router might change the source port number even if internally it's the same.)

The goal of this is to make sure all packets belonging to a given connection "stick" to a single path, avoiding packet reordering, while still providing load balancing.

The Linux 'traceroute' tool can use UDP probes with a specific port; running it with two different ports might reveal ECMP.

Remember that paths can be different in both directions (i.e. routing is not guaranteed to be symmetric), and "ping" only measures the sum of both A→B and B→A, whereas traceroute from A will show A→B but can't show B→A.

(And of course, the `ping` command doesn't use UDP at all, it uses ICMP, and there can be things that affect UDP but not ICMP or vice versa.)